# Root on Ubuntu Server 19.04

Tags: server, permissions, login, root, 19.04

my question about Ubuntu Server 19.04 is that my root isn't activating. 
I did anything I could find.

Problem is when I want to login on my Server with Root it pops-up "Access denied".

Also when I want to transfer files from my PC to Server it says access denied.

Can someone just help me by typing commands that I need to insert to enable Root, set-up password for it and make it just activated and work.

Comment: Why do you need to login as root? It is disabled and I don't see a case when it is really needed. Why don't you login with your user name and use sudo?

Comment: I can't transfer files from my PC to Ubuntu Server. 
It says Permission denied.
How can I enable it with SUDO?

Comment: It is very unclear what files and how are you transfering. You don't need to login root for that. Anyway you can enable root login.

Comment: I'm trying to transfer OSCAM files on my Ubuntu Server with WinSCP. But when I try it just says Permission denied.

Comment: What is the directory on the server you are transferring files to? What are the permissions?

Comment: usr/local/etc and users/bin folders are ones that we want to transfer files to.

Comment: transfet the files to the user home directory (/home/username), then copy or move them with sudo from Ubuntu cli. Very simple.

Comment: What do you mean move them with "sudo"?
Do I need to type some kind of commands or I just move them directly in WinSCP program? But I need to transfer them first to my home/username directory.

Comment: I tried to move my files to home/username and then tried to move them to my for example "etc" folder and it says again permission denied.

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this question with full details of what you're trying to do, what you've done so far, and exactly what has happened. That will automatically get this reviewed for possible reopening, and well as helping to clarify whether enabling root login is necessary or even sufficient for what you're trying to do.